# CSS3 transition within Awesome Icon Font and Text Hover

Tags: css

Why doesn't work the CSS3 Transition on the hover effect within the text and the coffee cup and why is at the bottom of the coffee cup a white border? I want to remove the border at the bottom of the cup.

I used the Awesome Icon Font within the whole thing.

Here's a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h98uf4fx/).
Here's my code:

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}

.contactbutton {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: transparent;
}

.contactbutton a,
.contactbutton a:link,
.contentbutton a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.contactbutton i {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.contactbutton a b {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.contactbutton a:hover i {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.contactbutton a:hover b {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="contactbutton"><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-coffee fa-2x"></i></i><b>Talk.</b></a></div>
```

Comment: You never said what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: The :hover effect isn't working and I want to remove the border at the bottom of the coffee cup. @inorganik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/inkedraskal/5g95efau/

Instead position one of the elements absolute and use "opacity" to transition between the 2 on hover

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

.contactbutton {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.contactbutton a,
.contactbutton a:link,
.contentbutton a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.contactbutton i {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.contactbutton a b {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
      position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
}

.contactbutton a:hover i {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.contactbutton a:hover b {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the `display` property. The white border is the default text underline that is applied by browsers to anchor tags.

Comment: So, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: To do what? Still haven't explained what hover effect your're after.

Comment: When you are hovering the text, the coffee cup is showing up.

Comment: with the text, or without it?

Comment: I want to hide the text, when I hover it, like in the example. But I want to have it with transition and without the border.